# new Highcharts from jQuery AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, highcharts

I'm trying to display a new Highcharts. Usually I use data from local server and i'm able to load data this way:

```
data : <php echo $jsonEncoded['values']?>,
```

The problem is : I have to load data from a remote server and it doesn't work! I really don't understand why...

You will find below my code :

```
            $.ajax({
         url: 'myurl',
          type: 'GET',
          dataType : 'json',
          success: function(json, statut){
            data_day = json['day'];
            data_values = json['js'];
            data_start = json['start'];
            options = {
              chart: {
                type: 'area',
                renderTo: 'container_health',
              },
              titile: {
                text: "text",
              },                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
              yAxis: {                                                                     
                title: {                                                                   
                  text: 'Pourcentage'                                                      
                },                                                                         
                max: 100,                                                                  
              },
              series : [{
                name: "test",
                data: data_values,
                pointStart: Data.UTC(data_start),
                pointInterval: 24*3600*1000
                },
              ]
             };
             chart = new Highcharts.Char(options);
            }
```

Then I have 3 alerts:

```
                alert(chart.series[0].pointInterval); //display well the date
            alert(chart.series[0].data[0].y); //display undefined
            alert(data_values); //display well values
```

So it seems, I don't have a problem when I want to access directly to a data from my JSON object (json['start']) but it seems it doesn't work when I try to access to my array from json['js']...

Is it a problem from Highcharts or the way to access to data?

EDIT :

All data don't work in options btw.

BR,

Comment: Do you receive any errors in the console? Chart is blank or nothing happen? How your JSON looks like ?

Comment: My JSON: {"day":2,"js":"[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]","start":"2015,1,11, 08, 20"}.. I receive this from highcharts Highcharts Error #12. But it's pretty sure it's about JSON because the remote server displays well this chart

Comment: This I found a mistake, i'm testing pointInterval intsead of pointStart... PointStart doesn't work too just unable to use JSON data in options

Comment: The problem is taht you have incorrect json. There should have data object with array of points. Not custom name like "js" and array as string.

Comment: In deed...then i tried to do json['js'].split(',') didn't work too. It works with well formated object, thank you